# How to import tables from the ER Diagram to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, entity-relationship, diagram, erd

I would need to import tables structures created manually in the ER Diagram to my SQL Server database.

Anybody please let me know the process.

Comment: The tool you were using to create ERD should have specific instruments to deploy it. Which is your tool?

Comment: I am developed ER Diagram with Visio tool

Comment: AFAIK Visio isn't a data modelling tool and has no instruments to deploy pictures drawn with it. Google some add-ins . See http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2010/04/16/visio-forward-engineer-addin-for-office-2010.aspx